# What is the fastest way to execute an INSERT INTO SELECT FROM statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

The following code is performing very poorly when there are merely tens of millions of records present in a view:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM dbo.SomeView
```

How could the code be modified so that inserting a lot of data works faster (ignoring the performance of the view)? IE: Are there any hints I could be using such as NOLOCK? Should I perform some other work prior to executing this command?

Comment: Is it the Insert or the select that takes time?

Comment: The insert. I have updated the question.

Comment: I have used different SQL Languages, but never seen this kind of inserts. It is always something like 'Insert into tblname(column1, column2,...) values(val1, val2,...)'. See for instance http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp or https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#BasicSyntax

Comment: NOLOCK is NOT a performance enhancing mechanism.

Comment: @LoekBergman It is valid SQL syntax, at least for MS Sql Server. I'm not sure on the technical details behind it, but the SQL Server remembers the order of the columns in the table. It inserts the val1 into col1, val2 into col2 etc. You technically don't even need to specify the select columns, or I mean you can short cut it by selecting all such as INSERT INTO table1_backup SELECT * FROM table1 works just fine. You could even do INSERT INTO table1_backup SELECT *, GetDate() FROM table1

Answer (score 0):

You might show us a copy of the execution plan, however in the absence of that you may consider any of the following:

- Could you include a where clause to limit the select?
- Are there other queries running in the background that could be causing some blocking?
- Are there index's on the gaining table you could remove prior to adding all the records, then add back.  That way you aren't writing the record and the index at the same time.